# MultiLevel Nested Object vs "multiple Nested Objects " in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

My requirement is to capture multiple marketplaces for a product in a elastic search.

index : ratingsindextest
Type : productchild

Each product will be having  multiple market-places and each market-place will have multiple regions and each region will have multiple countries , and i represented this as

```
{
  "ratingsindextest": {
    "mappings": {
      "productchild": {
        "_routing": {
          "required": true

             "productId": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "productMarkets": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "lobID": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              },
              "lobValue": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              },
              "regions": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                  "countries": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                      "country": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                      },
                      "status": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "regionId": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                  },
                  "regionName": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "productName": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "english"
          },
          "shortDescription": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "english"
          },
          "supplierId": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and my question is will there be any performance overhead because of multi level nested fields created as above ,  or is it advisable to change the mapping in a way that it accommodates plain list as below

```
{
  "ratingsindextest": {
    "mappings": {
      "productchild": {
        "_routing": {
          "required": true
        },
        "properties": {
          "productId": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "productMarkets": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "lobID": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              },
              "lobValue": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              },
              "region": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              },
              "countryId": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              },
              "countryName": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          },
          "productName": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "english"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the above mentioned way will have multiple nested documents with same Lob but multiple regions and each region having multiple countries .

Any Advice on which approach to follow is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Its always best if you can de-normalize your data but certainly not always possible. Also, *less nesting is better* - it will cost you less while performing search on nested.

> **Nested**:
>
> - Nested docs are stored in the same Lucene block as each other, which helps read/query performance. Reading a nested doc is faster than the equivalent parent/child.
> - Updating a single field in a nested document (parent or nested       children) forces ES to reindex the entire nested document. This can be very expensive for large nested docs
> - "Cross referencing" nested documents is impossible.
> - Best suited for data that does not change frequently
>
> **Parent/Child**
>
> - Children are stored separately from the parent, but are routed to the same shard. So parent/children are slightly less performance on
>     read/query than nested
> - Parent/child mappings have a bit extra memory overhead, since ES maintains a "join" list in memory
> - Updating a child doc does not affect the parent or any other children, which can potentially save a lot of indexing on large docs
> - Sorting/scoring can be difficult with Parent/Child since the Has Child/Has Parent operations can be opaque at times
>
> **Denormalization**
>
> - You get to manage all the relations yourself!
> - Most flexible, most administrative overhead
> - May be more or less performant depending on your setup

Quoted from : [Managing Relations Inside Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch)